# How to load the one page content without page refresh when another page button click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two pages (*checkout* and *order* page).
The *checkout* page contains a `confirme order` button. If the button is clicked the *order* page loads the data without a page refresh.

How can i do that. Please click me.

Comment: the answer is in your tags : jquery -> ajax -> php

Comment: dont expect spoon feeding here, lad. So, jQuery->ajax->php :)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an ajax call to get HTML from 'data.php' (or wherever you are getting your data from) and print that HTML into a div in checkout page.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "data.php"
}).complete(function(result) {
  $( div ).html(result);
});
```

Something similar to this.

For more on Ajax - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Not that ist wrong, but we as Comunity should't answer such Question swich don't show any efford by the OP

Comment: i get the data correctly.But i opened the orders.php in  anothet tap but the div contents are not changed.

Comment: When opening in another tab you have to get the updated data from your database not from the ajax call

Comment: Then how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

First take a simple button and call a jquery function onclick-

```
 echo '<a href="#" id="button">Click to change</a>';
```

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() { // wrap inside the jquery ready() function

//Attach an onclick handler 

$('#button').click(function(){

//Get the ID of the button that was clicked on (addition if you want any specific data, just pass that id in place of button)
var specific_id = $(this).attr("id");


$.ajax({
  url: "yourPHP_data.php", //This is the page where you will handle your SQL insert
  type: "POST",
  data: "data=" + specific_id, //The data your sending to yourPHP_data.php
  success: function(){
      console.log("AJAX request was successfull");
  },
  error:function(){
      console.log("AJAX request was a failure");
  }   
});

});

});
</script>
```

yourPHP_data.php page contain your code that you want to load and display, and you also find that data you have passed-

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
```

Comment: i get sucess function data. Now i need to chane the other page data without page refresh